# Adding multiple Filter Descriptors to a RadGridView - OR Statement VB

Tags: vb.net, vba, filter, radgridview

I'm trying to Filter a RadGridView with two Filters that work with an OR statement between them. Currently I have them working as an And. Is it possible to make this an OR Statement?

```
 searchFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(New FilterDescriptor("Order Number", FilterOperator.Contains, txt_PO_search.Text))
 searchFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(New FilterDescriptor("Supplier Ref", FilterOperator.Contains, txt_PO_search.Text))
```

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise that you can set the logical operator.

```
 searchFilter.LogicalOperator = FilterLogicalOperator.[Or]
```